# The button don't do the function

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a button using javascript, but the onClick event I've set does not seem work.

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('button pressed')
}

var BUTTON = document.createElement("button");
BUTTON.name = "not";
BUTTON.type = "button";
BUTTON.onclick = "myFunction()";
var textBUTTON = document.createTextNode("TEST");
BUTTON.appendChild(textBUTTON);
var output = document.getElementById("test");
output.appendChild(BUTTON);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

The button which is created by javascript appears, but the function, `myFunction()`, doesn't do anything.

If I make the button manually, with HTML, it works as expected

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('button pressed')
}
```

```html
<button name="not" type="button" onClick="myFunction()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Have you actually defined `myFunction()` anywhere? If so, can you show us the code for it? If not, then that's probably the issue.

Comment: `Button.onclick=myFunction`  - You just assigned text to the onclick method

Answer (score 7):

The issue is with this line:

```
BUTTON.onclick = "myFunction()";
```

It should be:

```
BUTTON.onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the function name without paranthesis and quotes in `onclick` attribute:

```js
 var BUTTON = document.createElement("button");
 BUTTON.name = "not";
 BUTTON.type = "button";
 BUTTON.onclick = myFunction;
 var textBUTTON = document.createTextNode("TEST");
 BUTTON.appendChild(textBUTTON);
 var output = document.getElementById("test");
 output.appendChild(BUTTON);

function myFunction(){
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While changing `BUTTON.onclick = "myFunction()"` to `BUTTON.onclick = myFunction` will work, you might also want to consider not manually assigning functions to the `onclick` property, but instead rely on event listeners instead:

```
// Bind click event listener
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

If you use an anonymous function in the callback, you can bind multiple functions to the same click event:

```
// Bind click event listener
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('button pressed')
}

var BUTTON = document.createElement("button");
BUTTON.name = "not";
BUTTON.type = "button";
var textBUTTON = document.createTextNode("TEST");
BUTTON.appendChild(textBUTTON);
var output = document.getElementById("test");
output.appendChild(BUTTON);

// Bind click event listener
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFunction();
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Make sure to assign function name without `""` and `()` .

Instead of this

```
BUTTON.onclick = "myFunction()";
```

Use

```
BUTTON.onclick = myFunction;
```

```js
 var BUTTON = document.createElement("button");
 BUTTON.name = "not";
 BUTTON.type = "button";
 BUTTON.onclick = myFunction;
 var textBUTTON = document.createTextNode("TEST");
 BUTTON.appendChild(textBUTTON);
 var output = document.getElementById("test");
 output.appendChild(BUTTON);
 function  myFunction()
 {
 alert('From myFunction')
 }
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>


<button name="not" type="button"
    onClick="myFunction()">
    TEST
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code

BUTTON.onclick = "myFunction()"

Replace this code

BUTTON.onclick = myFunction

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.setAttribute("id", "democlass");


var eventclick= document.getElementById("democlass");

eventclick.addEventListener("click", RespondClick); 
   function RespondClick() { 
          alert("working");
        }
```

You can check it.